# A topology question about bases

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the following collection of subsets of the real line forms a basis for the the real line:

$$ \mathcal{B} = \{ (a,b) : a < b, \; \; a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \} $$

My try:

Let $O$ be an open set of the real line. Take $x \in O$. To show $\mathcal{B}$ is basis for $\mathbb{R}$, Do I have to find an element $I \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in I \subset O $ ? I am having hard time understanding how to tackle this problem.

Also, why such a collection is useful basis?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s exactly what you must do. This is a useful base for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ for two reasons. First, it’s countable, and topologies with countable bases are especially nice. Secondly, its members, being just open intervals, have an especially simple form, which makes them relatively easy to work with.

I’ll get you started. Since $x\in O$ and $O$ is open in $\Bbb R$, you know that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq O$. Or, depending on how you’ve defined the usual topology of $\Bbb R$, you may instead know that there are $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subseteq O$. If it’s the former, let $a=x-\epsilon$ and $b=x+\epsilon$, so that in either case you have $x\in(a,b)\subseteq O$. Do you see that there must be a rational number $p\in(a,x)$? Can you go on from there to get an interval $I=(p,q)$ with rational endpoints such that $x\in I\subseteq O$?

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I have one question if you don't mind. I don't know how to find a rational p in $(a,x)$. Do I just have to use denseness?

Comment: @Learner: That’s right: use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. That immediately tells you that $\Bbb Q\cap(a,x)\ne\varnothing$, which is all you need. You won’t be able to pin down a specific rational, but you don’t need to: it’s enough to know that there is one.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Learner: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For any real number $a<b$, there exists two rational sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that:
$$
a\leq\cdots\leq a_n\leq a_{n-1}\leq\cdots b_{n-1}\leq b_n\leq\cdots\leq b
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a, \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b
$$
Then
$$
(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)
$$